# IPC : Connexion betwenn linux and Simulink

Tags: c, linux, simulink

For my project i had to write two programs (with C) that communicate with each other using the shared memory . The first program must write a message and the second program must read it . Now i have to implement the second program in Simulink so that the first program can now communicate with Simulink this time . I know that i have to use the S-Function to implement the code (for the secend program ) in Simulink but i coudln't copy the command in the write place .
Can someone help me please with that ?
Here is the code of the second programm :

```
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define CLEF 666
    #define LONGUEUR_SEGMENT 512 


    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
   {
     int semaphores;
     int memoirePartagee;
     struct sembuf manipSemaphores;
     char *attacheMoi;


     if ((memoirePartagee=shmget(CLEF,LONGUEUR_SEGMENT,0600)) == -1)
     {
     puts("Unable to access the shared memory segment");
     exit(1);
      }


      if ((semaphores=semget(CLEF,2,0600)) == -1)
      {
       puts("Unable to access the semaphore");
       exit(1);
       }

       /* Operation P(1) => we ask to access the resource */

       manipSemaphores.sem_num=0;
       manipSemaphores.sem_op=-1;

       semop(semaphores,&manipSemaphores,1);

       puts("I request to enter the resource");fflush(stdout);

       attacheMoi=shmat(memoirePartagee,NULL,0);


       if ((int)(*attacheMoi)==-1)
       {
       puts("Unable to attach !");
       exit(1);
       }
       else
       {
       printf("Address of attachment : %p \n",attacheMoi);
       puts("Contents of a memory of attachment ");
       puts(attacheMoi);
       shmdt(attacheMoi);
       manipSemaphores.sem_num=0;
       manipSemaphores.sem_op=1;
       semop(semaphores,&manipSemaphores,1);
       }


       puts("Unlock the other processes");
       fflush(stdout);

       /* Unlock the waiting semaphore*/

       manipSemaphores.sem_num=1;
       manipSemaphores.sem_op=-1;
       semop(semaphores,&manipSemaphores,1);


       return 0;
       }
```

Another question , what is the linux commande (in console linux) to connect the first program to Simulink ?